# How can I easily express that I don't care about a value of a particular data field?

Tags: haskell, hspec

I was writing tests for my parser, using a method which might not be the best, but has been working for me so far. The tests assumed perfectly defined AST representation for every code block, like so:

```
(parse "x = 5") `shouldBe` (Block [Assignment [LVar "x"] [Number 5.0]])
```

However, when I moved to more complex cases, a need for more "fuzzy" verification arised:

```
(parse "t.x = 5") `shouldBe` (Block [Assignment [LFieldRef (Var "t") (StringLiteral undefined "x")] [Number 5.0]])
```

I put in `undefined` in this example to showcase the field I don't want to be compared to the result of parse (It's a source position of a string literal). Right now the only way of fixing that I see is rewriting the code to make use of `shouldSatisfy` instead of `shouldBe`, which I'll have to do if I don't find any other solution.

Comment: The best way I can think to do this is to extend your type with logic variables and then unify instead of check equality. It's a powerful technique, but a bit non-trivial. If you build your type as a fixed point over a functor then it ought to relatively easy to slide the logic variables in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a `normalizePosition` function which replaces all the position data in your AST with some fixed `dummyPosition` value, and then use `shouldBe` against a pattern built from the same dummy value.

If the AST is very involved, consider writing this normalization using Scrap-Your-Boilerplate.

Comment: One disadvantage with this approach is that it is quite possible to write a buggy version of `normalizePosition` that still type checks (esp. when you use `syb`).  Parameterizing over the location type and using a `Functor` instance solves this problem and is less work (assuming you can derive the instances).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to parametrize your AST over source locations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data AST a = ...
  deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
```

Your `parse` function would then return an `AST` with `SourceLocations`:

```
parse :: String -> AST SourceLocation
```

As we derived a `Functor` instance above, we can easily replace source locations with something else, e.g. `()`:

```
import Data.Functor ((<$))

parseTest :: String -> AST ()
parseTest input = () <$ parse input
```

Now, just use `parseTest` instead of `parse` in your specs.